# How do i literally open a file using code in c++

Tags: c++, batch-file, cmd

I have written a code in which i want to open a HTM file when i select a particular option...

To achieve this i have created a batch file and opened it using system() as shown in code..
This is my code:

code:

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dos.h>
#include <process.h>
void main()
{
cout<<"Hello World";
delay(3000);
system("a.bat");
delay(1000);
}
```

a.bat code:

```
start iexplore.exe c:\Turbo\TC\BIN\Hello.htm
```

When i just use this line in command line it executes but when i want to execute it using c++ code i get a bad filename or command error...

Please tell me if i am going wrong somewhere here.. or what can i do.

Please help..

Thank You..:)

Comment: Most likely `iexplore.exe` isn't on whatever `path` is being used by your executable.

Comment: the delays are just for the heck of it will get rid of them in the main code...

Comment: Or `a.bat` isn't on `%PATH%`.

Comment: but it opens when i execute it normally

Comment: Does system use the shell? You might need to spawn this through cmd.exe. But you're not using 16-bit Turbo C are you?? There are probably Win32 APIs you can call for this if you can find a 32-bit compiler.

Comment: both the line of code i am using as well as the bat file when run individually are working but when i do so in the code it simply doesn't run and always gives me the same error

Comment: @Rup i didn't get you.. please tell me how i can go about it..

Comment: Try `system("cmd.exe /c a.bat");`

Comment: Don't you have to escape character in batch file too?

Comment: @Rup Just tried it..says "Illegal Command: cmd.exe."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since most of your code isn't particularly portable anyway, the right way is almost certainly to use `ShellExecute` to "execute" the HTML file directly. I, for one, would have to be pretty desperate before I'd put up with a program using IE to open HTML files.

`ShellExecute` is Windows-specific, but your code isn't *particularly* portable right now. I suppose Unix (or similar) systems wouldn't actually *stop* you from naming a shell script `whatever.bat`, but it's certainly uncommon. You certainly shouldn't expect `iexplore.exe` to be available on most though (nor for executables in general to have a '.exe' extension).

```
ShellExecute(NULL, NULL, "c:\\Turbo\\TC\\BIN\\Hello.htm", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CreateProcess()` API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425.aspx)

Comment: While `CreateProcess` works fine, using it does nothing to fix the OP's problem.